# Pulling a value from DataFrame based on another value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, facebook-graph-api

I'm playing around with the Facebook Ads API, I've pulled campaign data for one of my campaigns. If I have this dataframe:

```
[<Insights> {
"actions": [
    {
        "action_type": "custom_event_abc",
        "value": 50
    },
    {
        "action_type": "custom_event_def",
        "value": 42
    },]
```

How would I go about getting the value for `custom_event_def` out?

In my wider results, I first used `(df.loc[0]['actions'][1]['value'])` in my code which worked, but my issue with that is that `custom_event_abc` doesn't always appear and so the position of `custom_event_def`can change; meaning my solution only works some of the time.

Can `value` (42) be pulled out using a reference to the `action_type`?

Comment: What is the snipped you provided?  It looks like a partial made up json response (Not a DataFrame).  How did you create the DataFrame from that response and what does it look like?  Providing more information and a reproducible problem would help you get a solid answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will first create a dictionary `actions` with the content of "actions", iterate through all value it to find `custom_event_def` and then print the corresponding value

```
actions = df.loc[0]['actions']

for i, elem in enumerate(actions):
    if elem['action_type'] == "custom_event_def":
            print(actions[i]['value'])
```